# Remote: true form keeps reloading the page when submitting inline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form with a select dropdown:

```
= form_for @project, url: project_ga_data_period_path, method: :get, remote: true, html: {id: 'period_form'} do |f|
  = select_tag "period", options_for_select([['30 days' ,'30'], ['60 days', '60'], ['180 days', '180']]), class: 'form-control', onchange: ("javascript: $('#period_form').trigger('submit');")
```

As you can see it does not have a button, as I want the form to reload a partial on my page after a user selects something from the drop down list.

Here is my controller:

```
class GaDataController < ApplicationController
  def update  
    @chart_data = fetch_data

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Route:

```
get 'ga_data_period', to: 'ga_data#update'
```

JS file (update.js.erb):

```
$('#chart-container').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'documents/partials/index_chart_container' ) %>")
```

However on select the pages still redirects to a URL and I get an error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

If I'm using a submit button everything works fine.

Comment: What else is in the error? What line is it pointing at?

Comment: My initial thought is you need to declare an `html` respond_to as well. Typically I see an UnknownFormat when the page is trying to redirect without all the information.

Comment: With the html format it starts looking for the HTML template in the view folder. Basically the form submits as HTML and ignores the remote: true option

Comment: What are the logs showing? Because your form url is `project_ga_data_period_path` whereas your routes is catching requests for `ga_data_period` (Not `project_ga_data_period`)?

Comment: I sidestepped the problem for now by doing .click() on the submit button which I hid with CSS.